# Understanding Tycho error compilation: Missing requirement

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm compiling a eclipse based product with tycho and i'm having an error compilation that i don't know how to resolve.

My error code is:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: eu.geeking.gds.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: eu.geeking.gds.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

In https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting says next:

```
 Missing requirement: <artifact> requires '<dependency>' but it could not be found.

 This line prints one of the mandatory dependencies which cannot be resolved. This can either be a dependency of the seed artifact, or a dependency of an artifact which is a direct or transitive dependency of the seed artifact. See below for details on the <dependency> part of the message.
```

but my message is

```
"Missing requirement: <artifact> requires '<dependency>'; <plugin-name> but it could not be found."
```

I understand that plugin 'dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm' needs 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' dependency but i can't find it. I have written 'dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm' plugin and i don't have any error about 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' in eclipse and i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu` just refers to a p2 installer 'installable unit' (iu) it isn't a plug-in. So I think this is just saying the 'installable unit' `dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm` is required.

Comment: I read it as Greg reads it: `eu.geeking.gds.feature.group` of version 1.0.0 requires the missing installable unit `dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm` of any version (`0.0.0`).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to take  around over this problem and i will say something about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noob error.

The error was that the module `dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm`was not declared in the modules section of pom.xml and tycho couldn't find this plugin.

```
<modules>
        <module>dev.geeking.gds.toolchain.cortexm</module>
</modules>
```

Thank you guys!